# iPhone sharing photo on facebook

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook SDK to share photo on facebook, it is working fine on simulator but getting crashed on device. Can anyone help me getting rid of this?

crash log:

```
observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received
but not handled. Key path: state Observed object:     FBSession:
0x62a8b10, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0,
appID: 478897658797357, urlSchemeSuffix: ,
tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x628d1d0>,
expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:
0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:( "status_update" )
```